# Invoking public methods with invokespecial?

Tags: jvm

As anyone who can answer this question will already know, the JVM supports several bytecode instructions for invoking methods (`invokevirtual`, `invokespecial`, `invokestatic`, ...)

Most method calls on instance methods are made by `invokevirtual`, but private methods and initializer methods are called via `invokespecial`, as described in the JVM spec:

> The difference between the `invokespecial` and the `invokevirtual` instructions is that `invokevirtual` invokes a method based on the class of the object. The `invokespecial` instruction is used to invoke instance initialization methods as well as private methods and methods of a    superclass of the current class.

As I understand it, `invokevirtual` performs a vtable lookup to resolve the method while `invokespecial`, since the correct method implementation is known at link time, is resolved statically.

My question is,  why is `invokespecial` not used to call `public` methods in cases where the concrete class of the method owner is known at compile-time?  It seems to me that avoiding a vtable lookup would be desirable for efficiency reasons.  But obviously there is something that I don't understand about the JVM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, it's not that easy to know the particular call target at compile time. JVM can load new classes dynamically and can even redefine the existing classes in runtime. A public method that appeared non-virtual at compile time may happen to become virtual in runtime.

You are right that vtable lookup can have a performance impact. However, `invokevirtual` bytecode does not imply vtable lookup at all.

For example, HotSpot JVM does its best to devirtualize method calls. It relies on Class Hierarchy Analysis and Runtime Type Profiles to translate `invokevirtual` to direct calls or, even better, to inline "virtual" methods directly into the call site. Only true megamorphic call sites (that have 3 or more targets in runtime) undergo a vtable lookup.

That said, with modern JVMs there is no performance difference between `invokespecial` and `invokevirtual` when the target method is actually non-virtual.

Comment: As an addendum, especially those cases where a compiler could correctly infer that an invocation of a public target method can not end up at a different, i.e. overridden, method (those, the question was about), like final targets or direct results of the new operation, can be easily identified by the JVM’s optimizer or even by the linker, without the need to mark those invocations with a dedicated instruction like `invokespecial`. This even applies to old use cases of `invokespecial`, e.g. now, private methods within the same nest group are invoked via `invokevirtual` and optimized at runtime.