# Does the JVM's virtual function lookup have any optimization for final?

Tags: java, jvm

Suppose `obj` is of type `MetalScrollButton` (from Java Swing). The program can call, for example, `getButtonWidth()` on `obj`. Although a direction has to be specified at construction, `obj.getDirection()` would invoke `getDirection()` from `BasicArrowButton`. `MetalScrollButton` inherits a lot from `JComponent` and `Component`.

And obviously `MetalScrollButton` inherits all the standard things from `Object`, like the `getClass()` function, which is quite sensibly marked final.

So, would `obj.getClass()` cause a virtual function lookup starting at `MetalScrollButton` and going through the whole inheritance hierarchy all the way up to `Object` (that would be instantaneous from a human perspective, of course) or would the JVM know to go directly to `Object`?

And more generally, if the desired function is final at some level in the inheritance hierarchy, does the JVM have any indication of this fact, and the ability in the lookup process to skip the subclasses that can't override the final function?

Comment: This is vendor specific.

Comment: @Thorbjørn So it might be different between, say, HotSpot and Azul?

Comment: The JVM certainly knows which functions are final, though it's more likely to care about whether a function is ever _actually_ overridden than whether it _could be_ overridden.

Comment: Yes, HotSpot JVM *does* virtual call optimizations, and not only for `final` methods. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58241269/3448419

Comment: Also, the comprehensive study on Java method dispatch: https://shipilev.net/blog/2015/black-magic-method-dispatch/

Comment: @AlonsodelArte Yes.  This allows vendors to choose the way they see most fit. This is intentional.  The only thing you can be sure of being the same across all vendors, is what the Java Language Specification says.  It is very precise.

Comment: `getClass()` is special anyway. Even without the optimizations of method lookup (which also exist), it would be treated as a special, invariant operation (just read the class reference from the object) instead of a method invocation.